# How do I find a bound for $\|T_n x\|?$

Tags: functional-analysis

We have $T_n = S^n$ where $S : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ is defined by $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots ) \mapsto (x_3, x_4, x_5, \dots )$.

The notation $S^n$ is confusing to me, and consequently I'm not sure how to answer the problem. The bound is supposed to be $\|x\|$.

Comment: It's composition. $S^2=S\circ S$.

Comment: @DavidMitra In that case, I get $\|T_n x\| = \|(x_{2n}, x_{2n + 1}, ...)\| = (\sum_{i=2n}^{\infty} |x_i|^2)^{1/2} \le (\sum _{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i|^2)^{1/2} = \|x\|$. Correct?

Comment: It's actually $2n + 1$ in the above, not $2n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $T_nx=(x_{2n+1},x_{2n+2},\cdots)$ for all $n$ (being $x=(x_1,x_2,...)\in \ell^2$).

Then $\|T_nx\|_2=\sqrt{x_{2n+1}^2+x_{2n+2}^2+\cdots}\le\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+ x_3^2+ \dots}=||x||_2$

Answer (score 0):

$$||T^n x||_2=||(x_3, x_4, x_5, \dots)||_2=\sqrt{x_3^2+ x_4^2+ \dots} \leq \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+ x_3^2+ \dots}=||x||_2$$

Does this help?